# SQL query: Nested Aggregate Functions Not Allowed error

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird1.5

```
Select PAYMENT.CONTRIBUTION_NO, CONTRIBUTION.CONTRIBUTION_NO,
SUM(
  count(*) *
  (
    select sum(contribution.CONTRIB_AMOUNT)
    from contribution 
    where CONTRIBUTION.CONTRIBUTION_NO= PAYMENT.CONTRIBUTION_NO
  )
) as GT
from contribution, payment
Group By PAYMENT.CONTRIBUTION_NO, CONTRIBUTION.CONTRIBUTION_NO
```

Sorry I am really new to SQL and I am Having trouble with this code, I got an error saying that nested aggregates functions are not allowed, can somebody help me please . . . Sorry for the trouble and I really appreciate the help . . . Basically I wanted to stored a Total Value from the Count multiplied to a specific value from a row since it is grouped according to Contribution ID I wanted to get the total and stored it in GT

Comment: Please provide the exakt error message.

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output.

Comment: Everything i fine but when I added this "SUM( . . . )) as GT " in the query I get the Error Saying Nested aggregate not allowed I just wanted to total the result of this query "count(*)*(select sum(contribution.CONTRIB_AMOUNT)
 from contribution where CONTRIBUTION.CONTRIBUTION_NO= PAYMENT.CONTRIBUTION_NO " so I added SUM( . . . )) as GT in the query

Comment: @Mikky: In main query, there is no join condition between `contribution` and `payment` tables, or supposedly `contribution` shouldn't be there.  You problem is not clear. Kindly share sample data from both tables and expected result to help us help you. Also use explicit join if you need join.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you can't have an aggregate (`count`, and `sum`) inside another aggregate (`sum`). it is unclear what you are trying to achieve though (your query makes no sense to me), and on top of that, Firebird 1.5 is ancient and doesn't support some query constructs supported by more recent versions of Firebird.

Comment: @Mikky what is "fine" ? tewll what you have in your tables data and what you want as the output values and why. You query seems hard to explain. WHAT should it get in human-readable terms from what data ?

Comment: I wonder if anyone managed to understand what the topic starter wants from the data. Some thoughts about the query that I could hack together are to be read by @Mikky at https://pastebin.com/9MrSdA8h